# ORA-01722: invalid number regexp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below bit of code:

```
WITH aux ( str ) AS (
    SELECT
        'A     b s         d'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    regexp_substr(str, 'a', 'n') reg
FROM
    aux;
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

My current numeric character configuration is .,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    nls_session_parameters
WHERE
    parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

---

```
PARAMETER               VALUE
---------               --
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
```

Comment: since the third argument of the function should be numeric

Comment: You want `REGEXP_REPLACE` here, not `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.  But maybe you don't even need a regex replacement either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument to `regexp_substr()` is a number that specifies the position where to start searching.

If you are trying to specify the `match_parameter()`, then you need to specify all five arguments:

```
    regexp_substr(str, 'a', 1, 1, 'n') as reg
```

Comment: I consider this a typo question in its current form, and therefore did not attempt an answer.